# Can't include website link as a parameter while calling a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, callback

I've created a script using `request` and `cheerio` libraries to fetch different post titles and their corresponding links from a website. The script appears to be doing fine. If you take a look at the script below, you can see that I've used `getposts((item,link) => console.log({item,link}));` to call the function.

Now, the question is:

> How can I include ***startUrl*** (website link) as a parameter while calling the function keeping the rest of the logics as they are?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const startUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';

function getposts(callback) {
  request(startUrl, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function() {
        var items = $(this).text();
        var links = $(this).attr('href');
        return callback(items, links);
      });
    }
  });
}

getposts((item,link) => console.log({item,link}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new parameter for a url and pass in startUrl:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const startUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';

function getposts(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function() {
        var items = $(this).text();
        var links = $(this).attr('href');
        return callback(items, links);
      });
    }
  });
}

getposts(startUrl, (item,link) => console.log({item,link}));
```